# How to redirect output to client

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I'm a relatively new programmer in Python, and I have created this XMLRPC Server function as follows:

```
def shell(self, command, username):
    if username in loggedIn:
        return os.system(command)
    else:
        string = time.asctime() , " not logged in"
        string = "".join(string)
        return string
```

For the client side, I have written

```
command = raw_input ("$ ")
if command == "exit":
    exit()
else:
    server.shell(command, username)
```

However, when I run the command in the client program, the output would be in the server window and not the client window, something like this:

```
#client side
$ ls

#server side
#some results
localhost - - [14/Feb/2013 14:26:25] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

And the cd command is also broken (i.e. I couldn't change to other directories even when the command is issued). Is there any way of doing so, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.system doesn't return output to the command line, only the return code. If you want to capture stdout/stderr, you have to use subprocess.Popen. You can then also provide a working directory to execute your command in (using the cwd argument). As far as I know, cd might work in the shell, but won't change the working directory for the python instance. So the next call will not run in the directory you changed to. Using Popen with cwd should work.

Comment: I think for simple use cases it's better to use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of using `subprocess.Popen` directly.

Comment: So if I make a working directory for the user, do I place the `os.cwd` command inside the server code or the client code?

Comment: I think you should have it as an argument to the remote method you want to call and then call the subprocess method of your choice with cwd=user_directory on the server (don't actually call os.chdir). Alternatively, as you seem to have the user handling on the server, you can keep a mapping of users to their directories and get the directory from there. You would have one parameter less to your remote method, but its implementation would be the same.

Comment: @Barkuriu So I could do `return subprocess.check_output(command)`?